# How can I save a file on react folder from a url

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I need to download files from my database or my Onedrive and save them into react, these files are for my 3d models and the types is obj and mtl. For can I load dynamic objects from database I need this feature, how can I do this ? I'm using three.js in this project.

Today the project is loading the files stored in project but I like to find a away to pick this from a database or a storage provider.

I tried to do using fetch or something like else but I can't find a a way to do this correctly. I don't now if three.js supports url files I try to find but I don't see anything - can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless three.js provides a feature to take input from memory (in which case you can simply download the file into memory and pass it to three.js), doing this solely from a react app isn't possible. You will need to host your website on a server to have dynamic access to the public directory serving the react website.

Standalone react builds have static assets and can't be updated without creating another build